# how to disable required field in form

Tags: forms

I want to disable custom field in form, my field name is `field_course_display_ref` and it is entity reference.
I try  `$form['field_course_display_ref']['und']['#attributes']['disabled'] = 'disabled';` but when form submit it return **the `field_course_display_ref` is required** , I also try 
`$form['field_course_display_ref']['#disabled'] = TRUE;` but not work and field not disabled( user can change it).
also I try to remove `#require` with $form['field_course_display_ref']['und']['#required']=FALSE; but nothing happen and  when form submit, return  **the `field_course_display_ref` is required** .

How can I disable required field in form ?

I create form in callback of menu ,part of my code

```
function cdigitdev_pre_register_ym() {
    global $user;
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'cdigitdev') . '/js/cdigitdev.js', array('scope' => 'footer'));
    $nid = intval(arg(2));
    $productId = intval(arg(3)); //it will set to null if arg(3) not set ; equal to $productId=arg(3)? intval(arg(2)):NULL;
    module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
    $form = node_add('pre_register');
    $form['field_course_schedules']['#disabled'] = TRUE;
    //$form['field_course_schedules']['und']['#disabled'] = TRUE;
.
.
.
.
    return drupal_render($form);
}
```

Comment: Do hook form alter and change #required to false... Ideally $form['field_course_display_ref']['#required']=FALSE;

Comment: it is set to false  `field_course_display_ref (Array, 17 elements)
#attributes (Array, 1 element)
#weight (String, 1 characters ) 1
#tree (Boolean) TRUE
#language (String, 3 characters ) und
und (Array, 38 elements)
#access (Boolean) TRUE
#theme_wrappers (Array, 1 element)
#process (Array, 1 element)
#defaults_loaded (Boolean) TRUE
#parents (Array, 1 element)
#array_parents (Array, 1 element)
#processed (Boolean) TRUE
#required (Boolean) FALSE
#title_display (String, 6 characters ) before
#id (String, 29 characters ) edit-field-course-display-ref
#sorted (Boolean) TRUE`

Comment: @AnilSagar how can I disable field?

Comment: Update your question with your form implementation code.. Is your form a content type or custom form ?

Comment: @AnilSagar it updated

Comment: You need to use https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7 hook form formid alter to alter your form... You can get form id using  https://drupal.org/node/214592

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get it. Why do you want to **require input** from user **and at the same time prevent that input?** And if that's not what you want, why don't you just remove required when you set disabled?

Comment: i think same problem as this question , refer my answer https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/238574/how-to-make-a-field-in-custom-form-not-be-required/239181#239181

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found my problem, in this manner create form with :
  `module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
    $form = node_add('pre_register');`
`#required=false` and `#disabled=true` not work.

I  remove them form my function and put them in `form_alter`  and work correctly , both `#required` and `#disabled` .

My problem resolved but really I dont understand why it not work in my function and in hook_form_alter work .